# Spring Boot - displaying the OTP page, restrict access to other pages using their URLs (after successful authentication on the login page)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have created a Spring Boot web application, where after successful login, I have to send the user to the OTP page.

My problem is: When the user comes to the OTP page he can bypass it changing the URL, so he can access any page (i.e. big security risk) because the user has already authenticated from the login page.

How can I restict URL changes on the OTP page as it happens on the login page (using Spring boot-security), so the user can only get in if she/he is authenticated by OTP.

Comment: language and spelling

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is that on successful authentication - i.e. credentials entered on login screen are verified - the user is given limited access to the application. This limited access only allows access to the OTP page(s). Once the OTP has been verified, the user is given the full set of authorisation roles to which they're entitled.

A blog outlining this approach is available [here](http://altfatterz.blogspot.ie/2014/02/two-factor-authentication-with-spring.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create an [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html)

If the user requires a one-time password, strip their authorities, and give them a new one, say `ROLE_OTP`. `ROLE_OTP` can only use the OTP URL and not anything else.

```
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
    HttpServletRequest request,  
    HttpServletResponse response, 
    Authentication sourceAuthentication
) throws IOException, ServletException {

    UserDetails sourceUser = (UserDetails) sourceAuthentication.getPrincipal();

    List<GrantedAuthority> targetAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>( Arrays.asList( new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_OTP") ) );

    UserDetails targetUser = new User( sourceUser.getUsername() , "", targetAuthorities);

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken targetAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(targetUser, null, targetAuthorities);

    targetAuthentication.setDetails( sourceAuthentication.getDetails() );

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(targetAuthentication);

    response.sendRedirect("/otp-url");
}
```

If they pass the OTP, reload their real roles with loadUserByUsername()

```
Authentication sourceAuthentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

UserDetails sourceUser = (UserDetails) sourceAuthentication.getPrincipal();

UserDetails targetUser = userDetailsManager.loadUserByUsername(sourceUser.getUsername());

UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken targetAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(targetUser, null, targetUser.getAuthorities());

targetAuthentication.setDetails( sourceAuthentication.getDetails() );

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(targetAuthentication);
```

Comment: I will be Thankful to you sir, if you could help me out what changes would be required as Security configuration perspective. I mean @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/otp").hasAuthority("ADMIN")  as I am storing authorities in db while new user creation from admin account..or.antMatchers("/code").hasRole("PRE_AUTH_USER")....Kindly suggest bit confused

Comment: I don't do javaconfig only xml sorry